# Select from multiple collections within a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, studio3t

I have a mongodb with multiple collections. Each collection contains documents of identical structure (each collection represents one month of data).

I am using Studio 3T to make queries to the Mongodb. I would like to select all documents which fulfill a specific condition, e.g. represent data which contains 'Mexico' in the country field like the following:

```
// Requires official MongoShell 3.6+
use database;
db.data_Jan.find(
    { 
        "country" : /^.*Mexico.*$/i
    }
);
```

However,  I don't know how to do this across all collections, e.g. also select from 'data_Feb', 'data_March' etc.

What would be the fastest way to circumvent this issue without doing multiple queries? As I am new to mongodb, I appreciate any beginners tips.

Comment: Just to be clear, MongoDB itself does not speak SQL. This is a feature of the tool you are using that is doing translation. Since it's not "native" to the back end database,  translations are a :"best guess" and often only support a "sub-set" of functionality. The other tags you applied to the question are removed because this has nothing to do with the other products other than the supported features from this single product. If you want better results, then you should consider using the "native" language abilities of the database back end instead.

Comment: I edited the question, such that it now displays the native mongoshell query.

Comment: It does not really matter as there is no such thing as a UNION query with MongoDB. The real point is the design is wrong. Instead of creating multiple collections for different months you simply place a property on each document to indicate the month. You do need to change things for the different type of database engine. CRUD operations is one thing, and structure of course is the other. Not that it was ever a good idea to separate data like this in the first place.